# Wordpress Fatal error after migrating from php5.6 to php7

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My WP site is currently on php 5.6, but when updated to PHP7, I get the following fatal message and the white screen of death.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /home/s7280o8m/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1568 Stack trace: #0 /home/s7280o8m/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php(658): wpdb->db_connect() #1 /home/s7280o8m/public_html/wp-includes/load.php(404): wpdb->__construct('s7280o8m_wp891', 'K(p64@S137', 's7280o8m_wp891', 'localhost') #2 /home/s7280o8m/public_html/wp-settings.php(106): require_wp_db() #3 /home/s7280o8m/public_html/wp-config.php(90): require_once('/home/s7280o8m/...') #4 /home/s7280o8m/public_html/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/s7280o8m/...') #5 /home/s7280o8m/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/s7280o8m/...') #6 /home/s7280o8m/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/s7280o8m/...') #7 {main} thrown in /home/s7280o8m/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1568

F.Y.I :

1. Ran the PHP7 compatibly test and the plugins + theme were all good.
2. In trying solve the fatal error, I have deactivated all the plugins (one by one) and then re-activate (one by one), plus changed the theme, but the problem still persists.

Really would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions removed from php 7. Update your wordpress core to latest version.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using pretty ancient installation of your Wordpress as mysql extension was deprecated for a long time and is [removed from PHP7 completely](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysql.php). New code uses `mysqli` (directly or via PDO), you need to upgrade your Wordpress to recent codebase. Or downgrade PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are running the latest version of WordPress? (at the time of writing the current version is `4.8.1`, you can download it from this page: https://wordpress.org/download/)

It looks like you're running an outdated version because it refers to the `mysql_connect` function which has been deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and totally removed in PHP 7.0 ([as you can see here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)).

Also check for any plug-in installed which may be outdated: rename the `plugins` directory inside of `wp-content` if you want to disable every plugin at once.